# Send "share intent" (ACTION_SEND) from activity to service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

The task is to process somehow "share" intent in already running *service*.

As far as `ACTION_SEND` is an activity action we have to pick up intent in activity and broadcast it to service.

The problem is that it's logically to implement all "share intent" processing in service and use activity only for broadcasting intent.

So the service have to receive the intent (which previously received and broadcasted by activity) so we can call `getType()` and `get****Extra***()` to it in order to know what was actually shared and process this data somehow.

The intent we received in activity has the action `ACTION_SEND` (or `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`), right? So logically we can change action with calling `setAction()` to intent object and broadcast it to our service which is already listening to this particular action.

```
public class HandleShareIntentActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();     
        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(intent);

        // If I initialize empty intent there is no problem, 
        // I'll receive it in service            
        // Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

        broadcastIntent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_SHARE);
        broadcastIntent.setFlags(0);
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

        finish();
    }
    // ...
}
```

But that is not working, I'm not receiving this intent in service.
If I don't copy intent I got and broadcast an empty one, I do receive it in my service.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to start a service, call `startService()`, not `sendBroadcast()`. There is no reason to have the service respond to broadcasts, and you are adding security problems to your app by doing so.

Second, you have to call `startService()` on an `Intent` that will identify your service (e.g., `new Intent(this, ThisIsTheService.class)`). In your case, you are taking an `Intent` identifying an *activity*, using a copy constructor to make a copy of it, changing the action string, and then trying to use that.

And, since an `Intent` is `Parcelable`, you could just add it as an extra to a service-specific `Intent`:

```
startService(new Intent(this, ThisIsTheService.class).putExtra(EXTRA_SEND, getIntent()));
```

and your service can pick `EXTRA_SEND` out in `onHandleIntent()` (if it is an `IntentService`) or `onStartCommand()` (if it is not). This code snippet assumes that you define `EXTRA_SEND` to be some string somewhere.

Comment: Rats, I had the same answer *almost* done when yours showed up :-)  In any case, this is the correct answer, please accept it.

Comment: My service is already running and it shouldn't response to broadcasts, just to process data silently. The reason I don't start service every time I receive share event because running service contains a data that is a bit difficult to initialize (service is starting when external usb storage connected with OTG cable, service reads and parses data according to fat32 filesystem partition using UsbDeviceConnection and bulkTransfer. So when I receive share intent, I'm ready to process it and copy data on usb for example. If I initialize this data on every share event, It'll take a bit long time).

Comment: I understood how to do it with startService. Can it be done with running service? Can I still use sendBroadcast or should I use bindService?

Comment: @nicolausYes: "My service is already running and it shouldn't response to broadcasts, just to process data silently" -- you still use `startService()` to send the data to the service. You can call `startService()` as many times as you want; the service is *created* only when needed. "If I initialize this data on every share event..." -- put that logic in `onCreate()` of the service. "Can I still use sendBroadcast or should I use bindService?" -- I would use neither, but instead use `startService()`. Of your two options, `bindService()` would be better, but getting that right is tricky.